# Can I install Ubuntu to internal drive by running Unetbootin from Windows 10 external drive?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, windows-10, disk, unetbootin

I'm trying to use a hard disk install with Unetbootin to get Xubuntu on my windows 10 laptop. It doesn't have a CD/DVD drive to out discs in and I don't have any USBs lying around. So I'm trying to install from hard drive to my laptop like I did with Windows 7. When I select it from the boot menu it gives me a windows error screen as if I tried to use an unfinished install of Windows, asking me to try to recover with the would be installation disc. What do?

Comment: Added the extra info.

Comment: I'm trying to boot from the internal to install onto it. The same way I did with Win7 but Win10 works differently.

Comment: I meant CD/DVD drive.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no optical disk drive, you will need a LiveUSB [made by Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) (or [Linux](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0))  because [you can't install Xubuntu by booting from a Windows HDD](https://superuser.com/questions/1365294/install-ubuntu-by-hard-disk). In step 2 of that tutorial, when it says to get an ISO of Ubuntu, download [Xubuntu](http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/18.04/release/xubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso) instead.

Comment: Thanks. I'll get to it.